# How to get MySQL data into correct array structure

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I just finished getting a script to work by using a hard coded array like so:

```
dataArray[0] =[50,10,0.3,0.25,50,"FFF",3];
dataArray[1] =[50,10,0.3,0.2,50,"FFF",3];
....
dataArray[5] =[50,20,0.5,0.7,120,"FF0",4];
```

I put the contents of dataArray into a db table so I could eliminate the hard coded array.
I'm returning the data in a string from MySql with PHP, and a data dump shows that the number of values and the values themselves are correct.

However, I'm apparently not coding the data capture correctly because I'm not ending up with an array like my hard coded array (I need to maintain the structure of my hard coded array).

Here's the code for the db read:

```
function getSomeData(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GetSomeData.php",
        dataType: "text",
        success:function(result){
            setSomeData(result);
        }
    });
}

var someDataArray = new Array();
function setSomeData(resultData){ 
    var resData = resultData.split('^');//record split  
    for(var i = 0; i < resData.length; i++){
        someDataArray[i] = resData[i].split('#');//field split
        someDataArray[i].pop();//removes array element occupied by '^'

        if(i == resData.length - 1){
            setDataArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This for loop in setDataArray() doesn't create the correct array structure because someDataArray[x] is just a string:

```
var dataArray = new Array();
function setDataArray(){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
        dataArray[i] = someDataArray[i];
    }
}
```

So I tried putting someDataArray[x] in an array like so:

```
dataArray[i] = [someDataArray[i]];
```

But that didn't work either.

I've spent the 2 days trying to puzzle this out, reading blogs, and experimenting with everything I could think of, but no luck. I think it's a simple solution but I just can't get it.

Help?

---

---

**EDIT:**

After learning a bit about JSON and json_encode I now have my script working.  I wanted to post the way I did it to acknowledge that I received some valuable advice from Pat Burke.  The code below may not be what he had in mind but I massaged it until it worked. But I don't really understand why it works, so I'll have to do some more reading on json_encode I think.

Note that using dataType:"json" in the ajax call threw an error.

//GetSomeData.php

```
$return_arr = array();

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY idx ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    $resultArray = array();
    $resultArray[] = (int)$row['dc'];
    $resultArray[] = (int)$row['smlspc'];
    $resultArray[] = (float)$row['sclx'];
    $resultArray[] = (float)$row['scly'];
    $resultArray[] = (int)$row['lgspc'];
    $resultArray[] = (int)$row['colr'];
    $resultArray[] = (int)$row['diam'];
    if(count($resultArray) ==  7){
        array_push($return_arr, $resultArray);
    }
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);

mysql_free_result($result);
```

//new js

```
function getSomeData(){
    resultData = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GetSomeData.php",
        dataType: "text",
        //dataType: "json", //using this threw an error (see below)
        success:function(result){
            resultData = $.parseJSON(result);
            $("#p1").append("resultData.length =" + resultData.length + "<br />");
            //resultData.length =114 (it's a string not an array)
            $("#p1").append("resultData =" + resultData + "<br />");
            //resultData =
            //[[50,10,0.375,0.25,50,0,0],
            //[50,10,0.3,0.2,50,0,1],
            //[50,10,0.6,0.4,0,0,2],
            //[50,0,0.4,0.4,0,0,3],
            //[50,0,0.4,0.4,0,0,3]]

            for(var i = 0; i < resultData.length; i++){
                $("#p1").append("resultData[" + i + "] =" + resultData[i] + "<br />");
                //data displayed with dataType: "text"
                //resultData[0] =50,10,0.375,0.25,50,0,0
                //resultData[1] =50,10,0.3,0.2,50,0,1
                //resultData[2] =50,10,0.6,0.4,0,0,2
                //resultData[3] =50,0,0.4,0.4,0,0,3
                //resultData[4] =50,0,0.4,0.4,0,0,3

                //data displayed with dataType: "json"
                    //resultData is null
            }
        },
        //this has no effect with either dataType: "text" or dataType: "json"
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not simply return JSON from PHP and then add it as the return type in the jQuery GET? That way all the logic to format it as an array is done on the server-side and not in JS on the client...

Comment: @Pat Thanks for the help.  I stumbled my way into getting my script working, although I still don't really understand it.  Please see my edit for details.

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: @Pat The error message just states that the first object that attempts to access "resultData" is null, because "resultData" is reported as null as well (see the "data displayed" message near the bottom of my edit).

Answer (score 0):

if someDataArray[i] is a string of values separated by commas, you could do

dataArray[i] = someDataArray[i].split(',')